# Create colon as kernel/structuringselement for morphological operations in openCV and Python

Tags: python, opencart

I have a number of pictures that I need to process for image processing.

[image]

Basically I want to find the location of the `:-character` within my images. After inspecting the images, I find that is the only thing that all my images have in common. As all the images are taken from video streams, all digits will / can change at some time during the video stream.

Looking at the documentation of[`openCV`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) and this [post](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/skeletonization-using-opencv-python.html) I wrote the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def skeletonize(img):
   size = np.size(img)
   skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

   ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
   element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
   done = False

   while( not done):
      eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
      temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
      temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
      skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
      img = eroded.copy()

      zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
      if zeros==size:
         done = True

    return skel
```

Which yields the following output:

[image]

Next, I write my colon-based structuringselement:

```
img = cv2.imread('chi_int.JPG')
skel = skeletonize(img)
kernel = np.array([[0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0],
                   [0,1,0],
                   [0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0],
                   [0,1,0],
                   [0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0]], dtype=np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(skel,kernel,iterations = 1
```

How can I measure the number of rows filled with `zeros` are needed between the two `ones` in my structuringselement? By using the `skeletonize`-function, there should be **1 pixel** if my structuringselement when it has the correct size. How can I solve my script for this? Help is much appreciated!!

[image]

Note: I don't want to use Tesseract OCR as it is too slow

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic way to know the colon size until you find it, except if you know the font size. So you will have to try all possible options. But it doesn't seem to be efficient and reliable. I'd recommend the following.

1. Find connected components by `findContours` right after the thresholding.
2. Leave only those that are small and round (small `contourArea`, small `arcLength()/contourArea()`).
3. Calculate their centers.
4. Search for pairs that have small distance in x-direction and some reasonable distance in y-direction. This may be done very efficiently by sorting the array of points by the x coordinate.